# How to find all words with first letter as upper case using Python Regex

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, file, python-re

I need to find all the words in a file which start with an upper case, I tried the below code but it returns an empty string.

```
import os
import re

matches = []

filename = 'C://Users/Documents/romeo.txt'
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        regex = "^[A-Z]\w*$"
        matches.append(re.findall(regex, line))
print(matches)
```

File:

```
Hi, How are You?
```

Output:

```
[Hi,How,You]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a word boundary instead of the anchors `^` and `$`

```
\b[A-Z]\w*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TSn0R3/1)

Note that if you use `matches.append`, you add an item to the list and re.findall returns a list, which will give you a list of lists.

```
import re

matches = []
regex = r"\b[A-Z]\w*"
filename = r'C:\Users\Documents\romeo.txt'
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        matches += re.findall(regex, line)
print(matches)
```

Output

```
['Hi', 'How', 'You']
```

If there should be a whitespace boundary to the left, you could also use

```
(?<!\S)[A-Z]\w*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jiQ4En/1)

---

If you don't want to match words using `\w` with only uppercase chars, you could use for example a negative lookahead to assert not only uppercase chars till a word boundary

```
\b[A-Z](?![A-Z]*\b)\w*
```

- `\b` A word boundary to prevent a partial match
- `[A-Z]` Match an uppercase char A-Z
- `(?![A-Z]*\b)` Negative lookahead, assert not only uppercase chars followed by a word boundary
- `\w*` Match optional word chars

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HZNeQk/1)

---

To match a word that starts with an uppercase char, and does not contain any more uppercase chars:

```
\b[A-Z][^\WA-Z]*\b
```

- `\b` A word boundary
- `[A-Z]` Match an uppercase char A-Z
- `[^\WA-Z]*` Optionally match a word char without chars A-Z
- `\b` A word boundary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ikab3F/1)

Comment: Thank you for that, definitely don't want list of lists.

Comment: Is there a way to limit this to only words that start with an upper case letter and not all uppercase words

Comment: @SwayamShah You could use for example `\b[A-Z](?![A-Z]*\b)\w*` https://regex101.com/r/nqnjhO/1

Comment: Thanks for this, one problem is that some words still don't clear our, for example : SQL34,SQLLiteBrowser

Comment: @SwayamShah Should these not match? They don't consist of only uppercase chars right? https://regex101.com/r/hT9oEi/1

Comment: Sorry if the question wasn't clear enough, so just wanted words which start with uppercase and there should be no other uppercase in that word.

Comment: @SwayamShah So like this `\b[A-Z][^\WA-Z]*\b` https://regex101.com/r/Ikab3F/1

Answer (score 4):

You can use

```py
import os, re

matches = []
filename = r'C:\Users\Documents\romeo.txt'
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        matches.extend([x for x in re.findall(r'\w+', line) if x[0].isupper()])
print(matches)
```

The idea is to extract all words with a simple `\w+` regex and add only those to the final `matches` list that start with an uppercase letter.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/AXS8HT).

**NOTE**: If you want to only match *letter words* use `r'\b[^\W\d_]+\b'` regex.

This approach is Unicode friendly, that is, any Unicode word with the first capitalized letter  will be found.

You [also ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67237455/how-to-find-all-words-with-first-letter-as-upper-case-using-python-regex/67237511#comment118848792_67237537):

> Is there a way to limit this to only words that start with an upper case letter and not all uppercase words

You can extend the previous code to

```py
[x for x in re.findall(r'\w+', line) if x[0].isupper() and not x.isupper()]
```

See [this Python demo](https://ideone.com/ZTM3Pd), `"Hi, How ARE You?"` yields `['Hi', 'How', 'You']`.

Or, to avoid getting CaMeL words in the output, use

```py
matches.extend([x for x in re.findall(r'\w+', line) if x[0].isupper() and all(i.islower() for i in x[1:])])
```

See [this Python demo](https://ideone.com/yuPpke) where `all(i.islower() for i in x[1:])` makes sure all letters after the first one are all lowercase.

**Fully regex approach**

You can use PyPi regex module that has support for both Unicode property and POSIX character classes, `\p{Lu}`/`\p{Ll}` and `[:upper:]`/`[:lower:]`. So, the solution will look like

```py
import regex
text = "Hi, How ARE You?"
# Word starting with an uppercase letter:
print( regex.findall(r'\b\p{Lu}\p{L}*\b', text) )
## => ['Hi', 'How', 'ARE', 'You']
# Word starting with an uppercase letter but not ALLCAPS:
print( regex.findall(r'\b\p{Lu}\p{Ll}*\b', text) )
## => ['Hi', 'How', 'You']
```

See the [Python demo online](https://tio.run/##jc0xC4JAGIfx3U/xxwY1pKUtiJAIHByihghczrz04Lo7Xl/RCD/7hTS1uTzj83Nvbq3Zeq9ezhKDZCPHgOXI2CPMVYrcDsguJ9xtfwiDFW6WanQsiJVpMChuIQx65yQ9RCehJbOkXeBIGY5/w81TmVpoHVNUVqX7FP00d1qXVZRi1hIki9@oeoaxjKwojtn5usjS/5j3Xw) where

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `\p{Lu}` - any uppercase letter
- `\p{L}*` - any zero or more letters
- `\p{Ll}*` - any zero or more lowercase letters

Comment: Thank you that works, is there a way to learn more about Regex, I always seem to get confused about them.

Comment: Thank you for the update, so I still see the word "SQLiteBrowser" in the output, shouldn't not x.isupper() take care of it?

Comment: @SwayamShah `SQLiteBrowser` is not ALLCAPS word. It is a CaMeL word. Do you want to avoid getting CaMeL words, too?

Comment: Yes, so only words which start with upper case and should not include any other capital letters.

Comment: @SwayamShah So, right now, `regex.findall(r'\b\p{Lu}\p{Ll}*\b', text)` works as expected. `matches.extend([x for x in re.findall(r'\w+', line) if x[0].isupper() and all(i.islower() for i in x[1:])])` will do. See [this Python demo](https://ideone.com/yuPpke).